# length of an dynamic object

Tags: c#, ajax, dynamic

[object picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjAKR.png) how can I get the lenght of a dynamic object , I recieved the object from the Ajax function, and I'm trying to build a list from the data in the dynamic object but it's not working whrn I used the matchesData.lenght.

```
 public string updateQueue( dynamic  matchesData)
      {
          MatchesQueues m = new MatchesQueues();
          List<MatchesQueues> MQ = new List<MatchesQueues>();
          for (int i = 0; i < matchesData.length; i++)
          {
              MatchesQueues  matchqueue = new MatchesQueues(matchesData[i].FieldId, matchesData[i].MatchId, matchesData[i].NumInQueue);
              MQ.Add(matchqueue);
          }

          int rowsAffected = m.updateQueue(MQ);
          if (rowsAffected == 1)
          {
              return "Time Updated";
          }
          else
          {
              throw (new Exception("Time didn't updated"));
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `matchesData` is of `dynamic` type, there is no way you know that it has a `length` property but if you sure that it has then try casting it to that particular type before accessing the `length` property. For example, if you know that it's of `string` type then cast it to string type and then access the property like

```
var data = matchesData as string;
if(data != null)
{
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {...}
}
```

Comment: the problem is that it's an complex object, see in the picture . that is the reason in the first place I decided to use dynamic instead of a list of lists of strings. I added a picture of the object

Comment: @MosheEzer, what's the actual type of `matchesData`? post the class definition for that for better clarification? a picture won't help much.